# Mysql Query, or condition is not working

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT UT_10, LT_10, ACT_10, LT_10 - ACT_10, UT_10 - ACT_10  
FROM distributor  
WHERE (  
          LT_10 - ACT_10 <>1  
       OR LT_10 - ACT_10 <>2  
      )  
      AND ACT_10 <>10  
      AND 
     (  
          UT_10 - ACT_10 =1  
       OR UT_10 - ACT_10 =2  
     )  
      AND ACT_10 <>10
```

I wrote this query in mysql. I don’t want 1 or 2 result but 1 is display in  result please help me.
or condition is not working with mysql query.

you can see here result: [**CLICK HERE FOR LARGE IMAGE**](http://metricglobal.com/mysql_query_problem.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
LT_10 - ACT_10 <>1
OR LT_10 - ACT_10 <>2
```

With

```
LT_10 - ACT_10 NOT IN (1,2)
```

Results where `LT_10 - ACT_10` equals `1` are returned by your original query because you used `OR`, if you only wanted results where it is not equal to either you should have used `AND`. This can be shortened using `NOT IN` as shown in my example above.

Your original condition serves no purpose as `LT_10 - ACT_10` can only take one value - it will never be equal to `1` and `2` (which is what would be needed for both parts of the original `OR` condition to evaluate to `false`)

Comment: No problem. If you receive an answer to your questions on Stack Overflow which you are happy with, you should mark them as the accepted answer by clicking the tick to the left of it.